# How can I drag a view horizontally?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

In controls like ListView and Gallery you can drag items in one direction vertical or horizontal.

I have a TextView that I drag it successfully. But I want to move it in horizontal direction. how can i implement it?

Thanks,

my code:

```
public class MyDragShadowBuilder extends View.DragShadowBuilder {
    private static View view;

    public MyDragShadowBuilder(View v) {
        super(v);
        view = v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point size, Point touch) {
        width = getView().getWidth();
        height = getView().getHeight();
        size.set(width, height);
        touch.set(width / 2, height / 2);
    }

    private int width, height;

    @Override
    public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
        view.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

in my activity:

```
tv.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("dot",
                    "Dot : " + v.toString());
            View.DragShadowBuilder myShadow = new MyDragShadowBuilder(v);
            v.startDrag(data, myShadow,(Object) v, 0);
            return false;
            }
        });
```

I want to simulate a Gallery. I have 10000 photos to show by it. My gallery can show 10 photos. I want to drag the LinearLayout of my gallery which is containing the gallery's content horizontally and when the LinearLayout reached to the end of window like SlidingDrawer, change its content and show the next 10 photos. SlidingDrawer is a good solution but it has some limitations. When you set your whole LinearLayout as its **handle** it can not be clicked. When you set a separated **handle** for it, you can not determine the position of **handle** relative to the **content**.

Comment: Have you tried putting it in a HorizontalScrollView?  
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html

Answer (score 8):

Starting with Bluefalcon's advice, I came up with something like:

```
// in onCreate of the containing view
dragButton.setOnTouchListener(new DragExperimentTouchListener(dragButton.getX(), dragButton.getY()));
```

...

```
public class DragExperimentTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    public DragExperimentTouchListener(float initalX, float initialY) {
        lastX = initalX;
        lastY = initialY;
    }

    boolean isDragging = false;
    float lastX;
    float lastY;
    float deltaX;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

        int action = arg1.getAction();

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && !isDragging) {
            isDragging = true; 
            deltaX = arg1.getX();
            return true;
        } else if (isDragging) {
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

                arg0.setX(arg0.getX() + arg1.getX() - deltaX);
                arg0.setY(arg0.getY());
                return true;
            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                isDragging = false;
                lastX = arg1.getX();
                lastY = arg1.getY();
                return true;
            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                arg0.setX(lastX);
                arg0.setY(lastY);
                isDragging = false;
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also put the initialization of lastX and lastY

        ```lastX = initalX;
        lastY = initialY;```

inside the `if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && !isDragging)`.


First, because it's sure that the view has already been drawn in onTouch() and you'll get the correct x and y. Second, so that it will be initialized again every start of dragging even if the view has already moved because of previous dragging.

Comment: It's work but sometimes (i think dragging to parent view) ACTION_CANCEL making problem. I remove "else if ACTION_CANCEL" and edit "else if ACTION_UP" to "else. And it's solved :)

Comment: can I combine this code with onClick and onLongClick listeneres?

Comment: @coder123 I don't know I'd start a new question for that.

Answer (score 3):

Horizontal Scroll view is the simplest horizontal drag option in android...

[HORIZONTAL SCROLL VIEW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html)

Try that....and inside the specified,give the textview or any layouts or widgets you prefer to use...and it will work even for dynamic procedures...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to Scroll the use the Horizontal scroll view as suggested by the rest.

But if you mean drag as in "drag and drop" then you can do the following.

- Set up a touch listener on the `TextView`
- Listen to all events after `ACTION_DOWN` and events `ACTION_MOVE`
- Get the `x` and `y` position from the above events
- use the API `setTop` and `setLeft` and set them to `x` and `y` you get above
- then call `invalidate` on the whole view

This should drag the UI element around the screen.

Answer (score 1):

HorizontalScroll view is perfect solution for this refer the blog here
http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/01/scrollview-and-horizontalscrollview.html

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 0):

You can use horizontal scroll view to emulate a horizontal sliding gallery.