# How to switch the image one by one through left swipe or right in android?

Tags: android, android-gallery

I have bunch of images.i want show all images one by one through swipe left or right.Can any one help me.

Comment: Did u try using gallery? here is the link - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/7886010/779408

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you can use page curl effects for images.

You can turn right or left. Hope this might helps you.

http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/

Answer (score 1):

Use ViewPagerIndicator.It works well for your requirement.

The best example is there.Jake Wharton's View Pager indicator.

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: not page indicator.i want switch images one by one in one layout.

Comment: @yugesh: u r using images in every layout and not in gallery or sd card?

Comment: when i click the button.i show the pop up window in tat i will show all the images.

Comment: its nice tutorials i use tis some wher else.

Answer (score 0):

For apis < 16 you can use the Gallery widgvet (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html)

Another solution is to use a Viewpager, please check this post: [Gallery of images using ViewPager + zoom in ImageViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089380/gallery-of-images-using-viewpager-zoom-in-imageviews)