# How to swipe and switch between two images?

Tags: android, image, swipe

At the top I have local car plate image with edit text inside.

I need to swipe left or right and switch local car plate image to global car plate (new) image to enter less restricted value.

All other information below should stay and do not move.

Please recommend me how could I do that in Android?

Comment: https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView. check the photoview

Comment: See this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832947/how-to-switch-the-image-one-by-one-through-left-swipe-or-right-in-android/14833215#14833215

Comment: I have tried view pager and it works fine with images. But I can't switch between layouts, because I need image and 2 EditText inside. https://github.com/chiuki/android-swipe-image-viewer

Answer (score 0):

Use [ViewSwitcher](http://samplecodez.com/android/viewswitcher.php)

```
<RelativeLayout
android:background="#0000FF"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"  >

<ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/smile" />


<TextView
    android:text="Loading..."
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progressbar" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:background="#FFFF00"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
        android:text="Finished!"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/smile" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use gestureoverlayview to handle touch and swipe detection please refer this site

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.html